# Does the File class create a file if we specify the name of the file?

Tags: java, file

When I create a new object from the File class:

```
File file = new File("C://Desktop/file.txt")
```

Does it create a new file called **file.txt** or does it return a NullPointerException?

Comment: the javadoc says that it creates an instance but you are right, I'll try myself.

Comment: A File instance (a Java object) is not the same as a file in the file system. A new file in the filesytem is created by calling [File.createNewFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()) or implicityl by writing to a FileOutputStream or FileWriter.